# Gridview stretching out of div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I have following html and asp.net gridview contained inside the div

```
<div id="div1" style="float:left;border-style:solid">
<asp:Gridview id="g1" runat="server">
</gridview>
</div>
```

The gridview is stretching out of div. What should I do to have div to contain the gridview within its border?

It get stretched from below(height)
Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give the gridview width="100%".

Comment: it gets stretched from below (height)

Answer (score 0):

try the following CSS :

```
#div1{
    width : 300px; /*whatever you want to set*/
    overflow-x : scroll;
}
#div1 table
{
    width : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like lostie said, use this.

```
<div id="div1" style="float:left;border-style:solid">
<asp:Gridview id="g1" style="width:100%;" runat="server">
</gridview>
</div>
```

This works if your div is a fixed width, example: 300px;

**You can also go to edit columns, and click on each of the different columns and set their width.

Answer (score 0):

> "It get stretched from below(height) Please help, Thanks"

Is the grid also floating?  If so, try adding a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) solution to the div.

```
<div class="group box-styles">
    ...grid...
</div>

.group:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
.group {
 zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```